# Show/hide comment status in front-end

Tags: comments, front-end

Is it possible to put a button in the comments(front-end) that would show/hide comments that are in spam status in the current post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; you can use [`get_comments()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/) to query comments and specify `spam` as the `status`. Placing the button will depend on your theme, but the below is how to get the comments marked as spam (tested):

```php
get_comments( array(
    'post_id' => $post_id,
    'status'  => 'spam',
) );
```