# Add a toggle show/hide spam button in comments

Tags: comments, front-end

Is there a way to insert a button in the comments that will toggle show/hide spam statuses in the current posts while leaving the other comments unchanged?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show/hide comment status in front-end](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/417221/show-hide-comment-status-in-front-end)